# Youtube Api V3.0 .NET Upload Issues and Oauth2 1.6 DLL's are not matching with Youtube Api V 3 1.7 DLL

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api

I am trying to use Youtube Api V3.0 .NET samples from [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet) but it didn't work.  Oauth2 1.6 DLL's are not working with Youtube Api V3 1.7 DLL's. Where can i find the correct DLL's?

I am waiting for your suggestions.

I am sorry if i used wrong grammar.

Thank you.

Comment: .Net samples are not working. I think they did not check what they wrote, because if they did they will see it does not work at all. Everybody says that we have to move to v3 but if there is no support or updates, how can we make it work? We are waiting for nothing. Please let us know if you are on it ot not. You can give us ETA.

Comment: @JeffPosnick , you are invited sir.

Comment: Nobody is answering me. That means Youtube does not support .NET users anymore. It's so sad.

Comment: Now they blocked me to see Youtube Api Questions. What a nice reaction! 

Thank you for being rude to your user..

Comment: Nobody is answering me, so i will keep updating this situation. I hope that somebody from Youtube API Team will answer..